# How to disable Left swipe gesture in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I am trying to use `createStackNavigator` and `createDrawerNavigator` in my app. Application is working fine but somehow I am stuck and I tried my hard but did not resolve my issue. Actually I used `DrawerNavigator` there I am navigating user to an another screen and it the moment user has been navigated but when I swipe from left side menus is appear . I want to restrict a user to swipe a menu when he/she navigated to desired screen .

**Code**

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation-drawer";
import React from "react";

import Login from "../components/login/Login";
import Signup from "../components/signup/Signup";
import Pharmacy from "../screens/pharmacy/pharmacyScreen";
import MainApp from "../screens/MainApp";
import MainAppContent from "../screens/MainApp/MainAppContent";

const mainStack = createStackNavigator({
  MainApp: {
    screen: MainAppContent,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
      gestureEnabled: false
    }
  },
  Login: {
    screen: props => (
      <Login
        {...props}
        headerImage={require("../assets/login-header.png")}
        title="Welcome"
      />
    ),
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false
    }
  },
  Pharmacy: {
    screen: Pharmacy,
    navigationOptions: {
      gestureEnabled: false
    }
  },

  Signup: {
    screen: Signup
  }
});

const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  MainApp: {
    screen: mainStack
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(drawerNavigator);
```

Comment: It is working for just keeping  **navigationOptions: { gestureEnabled: false }**

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [drawerLockMode](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/drawer-navigator/#drawerlockmode) to `'locked-closed'`on your `drawerNavigator`